# I would feel bad if I don't tell you this. vs I would feel bad If I didn't tell you this.?

Tags: word-choice

When talking about a imaginary possibility in the future, which one should I say? In this case, I wanna say the sentence before telling a person something.

Another example: I would be happy if you come to my birthday party next week. < Is this correct?

Comment: *I would be happy if you **would/could** come to my birthday party next week.*

Comment: The right one is: If I didn't tell you this.

Answer (score 1):

The second statement is correct because it speaks of a hypothetical future and is talking about something you "didn't" do earlier in that future.

Your use of "I would" is correct (and not "I will") because it is in keeping with the idea of an imaginary scenario.